# How can I update the Mercurial version MercurialEclipse uses?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

I am getting the following error in eclipse when trying to use MercurialEclipse:

> abort: requirement 'dotencode' not supported!. Command line:
>   D:\DEV\Flex\Workspaces\MothersRingsKrake:hg -y status -marduc

I looked it up and it [says](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RequiresFile):

> If an older Mercurial version tries to access a repository that was
>   created by a newer Mercurial version, an error message like
>
> **abort: requirement 'dotencode' not supported!**

So how can I make my MercurialEclipse plugin use the newer version of Mercurial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the version of the Mercurial (in-built) used by Eclipse is different from the one installed in your machine, you could configure the Mercurial plugin to use the newer `hg` executable. You can do so, by visiting the "Mercurial" sub-menu under the "Team" menu in the Preferences dialog (Window-> Preferences), and explicitly specify the location of the `hg` executable.

[image: Changing the Mercurial executable used by Eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I updated to latest TortoiseHG.
Fixed it by installing `Mercurial-2.0.2`